# Import Self Created Python Modules to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying to bring in a .py file that I have created and hosted in my Jupyter environment to a notebook. I have tried the following method, but it gives me an error.

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/file.py')

import file.py
```

I have several functions saved in this file that I want to be able to call, but when I run the above I get an error that the file.py was not able to be loaded in. Is there a special way within notebooks to load in created .py files?

Comment: just the path to the folder not to the actual file

Comment: I tried that but still got the error. I know it is confusing in my above code snippet, but I actually only follow the path to the folder, not the file itself.

Comment: try `os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = '/path/to/folder'` (although iirc sys.path should really be enough... but im not sure on that)